# Coordinate-systems and vector fields.

Tags: coordinate-systems, vector-fields, cylindrical-coordinates

Consider this  [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/737401/330899) that I asked on Physics SE. Rereading it I realized that when I said "...are left with two possibilities: a circumferential field and a longitudinal field", I assumed that there were no other possible directions on which the field can depend. Is this assumption justified? Or equivalently, can any coordinate system with three orthogonal axes, is enough to solve a vector field problem?

Comment: You can represent any vector field in a coordinate system with another coordiante system and the solution would be the same, now if a vector field problem is solvable then it is solvable in any coordinate system. Was that your question?

Comment: @HakemHa The problem that I am facing is how can we consider longitudinal and circumferential fields as separately as we do in solving the question I mentioned. For example, the field could have had a sum of circumferential and longitudinal components (which it does not though). I think that this problem was constructed this way to not think much about the math in it, and having little to no experience in solving real-world EM problems I think I have built up this confusion.

Comment: The symmetry transformations (of the source) that you are hinting about in your question(s) are ways of eliminating the possibility of certain components of the magnetic field.  You can consider a hypothetical B field vector that points only in, e.g., the longitudinal direction. If that vector is changed under the symmetry transformation of the source then you have eliminated the possibility of that vector being a solution, as well as *any vector that has a nonzero component in that direction*.  This just follows from $\vec{B} = B_x \, \hat{\imath} + B_y \, \hat{\jmath} + B_z \, \hat{k}$